# Class Decorator (instance level)

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class, ecmascript-next

I'm trying to add a class `decorator` on a property and modify this property in the `instance`.

This is working well with `typescript` however I don't want to use `typescript`, only `babel` but not any other compiler.

My guess is that the `target` inside the `el` function is the `class` instead of the `instance` which is not the case when using `typescript`

If anybody has any idea on how to make this work using only `babel` and without `typescript`

Demo with typescript : https://jsfiddle.net/w7xnwbdz/

Demo with babel only : https://jsfiddle.net/w7xnwbdz/1/

```
function el(type) {
  return function descriptor(target, key,dec) {

    let value = target[key];
     const getter = function() {

      return value;
    };

    const setter = function(newVal) { 
      value = document.createElement(type);
      value.innerHTML = newVal
    };

    if (delete target[key]) {
      Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
        get: getter,
        set: setter,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
      });
    }
  }
}


class App { 

  @el("div")
  logo = "message"

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.logo)
  }
}

let app = new App();
```

Comment: You can't use decorators in JS.

Comment: @JohnKennedy He is using Babel to use experimental es-next features for JS.

Comment: Decorators are not part of ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently come across a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306585/babel-decorator-of-decorated-class-properties-is-called-before-instantiating-c). Therefore, I can tell you that when using Babel, you will have to use the `PropertyDescriptor` argument of your decorator to fetch the initial value and set the property `accessors`.

```
function el(type) {
    return function descriptor(target, key, dec) {
        const { initializer } = dec;

        let value = target[key] || null;

        const getter = function () {
            console.log('_getter_')

            if (!value && (value = initializer.call(this))) {
                setter(value);
            }
            return value;
        };

        const setter = function (newVal) {
            console.log('_setter_');

            value = document.createElement(type);
            value.innerHTML = newVal
        };

        return { get: getter, set: setter };
    }
}
```

As per request, I have updated your decorator to make it work for **just** Babel.

The additional setter call in the getter method is to set the requested return value when the decorated property is initialized at the class level (outside the constructor or member methods).

> If you want it to be compatible with TS, you have to check if the PropertyDescriptor is set and *not* use the initializer constructor function to fetch the initial value. Replace the calls with `target[key]` instead.

I am not sure whether or not it is best practice to return a new object with just the property accessors or to return the initial PropertyDescriptor from the decorator method. It just omits having to delete the existing properties suchs as `value` and `writable` every time a call is made to the decorated property.